# React Native OSX CRNA Compilation of µWebSockets has failed C++11 compiler

Tags: macos, c++11, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

Got this issue after ejecting from Expo (with ExpoKit). Had a working environment before ejecting. `npm run ios` will run with this issue repeating over and over:

> Origin: Worker (PID 6336) 12:18:06:    [Error] Error: getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND lcalhost 12:18:06:     at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
>   12:18:06:     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete]
>   (dns.js:76:26)

Expo XDE will not run at all and repeats this message. XCode includes C++11 compiler.

> Error: Compilation of µWebSockets has failed and there is no
>   pre-compiled binary available for your system.  Please install a
>   supported C++11 compiler and reinstall the module 'uws'.

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "OurApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "jest-expo": "^23.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "remotedev-rn-debugger": "^0.8.3"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch",
    "postinstall": "remotedev-debugger --hostname lcalhost --port 5678 --injectserver",
    "eslint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint"
  },
  "remotedev": {
    "hostname": "localhost",
    "port": 5678
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "expo": "^23.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-23.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.18.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.19.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.19",
    "react-navigation-redux": "^0.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.12"
  }
}
```

## app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "isDetached": false,
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "sdkVersion": "23.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "primaryColor": "#ffde00",
    "name": "OurApp",
    "description": "Desc",
    "icon": "./resources/icon.png",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "slug": "our-app",
    "scheme": "ourapp",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "se.comp.expo",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "key"
      },
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "isRemoteJSEnabled": true,
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "associatedDomains": [
        "myDomain.com"
      ]
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "se.comp.expo",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "key"
        }
      },
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
      ]
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./resources/icon_notify.png",
      "color": "#ffde00",
      "androidMode": "collapse",
      "androidCollapsedTitle": "#{unread_notifications} new"
    },
    "loading": {
      "icon": "./resources/icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000",
      "backgroundImage": "./resources/splash.png",
      "hideExponentText": true
    },
    "splash": {
      "backgroundColor": "#000000",
      "image": "./resources/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "barStyle": "dark-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffde00"
    },
    "facebookAppId": "id",
    "facebookDisplayName": "OurApp",
    "facebookScheme": "fbId",
    "androidShowExponentNotificationInShellApp": true
  }
}
```

Comment: check yours [Solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17410)

Comment: @SyedZainAli you're right, something's broken in the environment. however, there's no clear solution for OS X. I've reinstalled RN and Expo. C++11 compiler is supposedly included in XCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@SyedZainAli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6621743/syed-zain-ali) mentioned this might be caused by environment. A few things to try then is:

- Remove node_modules, run `npm cache clean` and reinstall
- Reinstall NodeJS
- Create a new app using CRNA and compare

In my case *ejecting* and using *Expo react-native branch* (default behavior) causes the issue. Changing back to official react-native npm package resolves the issue. So should be something on Expo's side.

Comment: The problem I had was that the `uws` version I was trying to install (via react native) isn't compatible with Node 10.x. Reinstalling the latest version of Node 8 fixed the issue.

Comment: @ephemer analysis of the problem is correct and pertinent. If you want to keep Node 10.x, you can add uws 10.148.0 to your devDe

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this may help you, but it fixed my issue within docker.

In Docker file

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

`FROM node:8.9-alpine`

`RUN apk add --update \`
`libc6-compat`

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Needed `libc6-compact`

so try installing `libc6-compat`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (below) when I was trying the start an app I got from my team in Expo. And it turned out that `uws` version in the project was not compatible with the Node version I was using. - node v10.15.0

Switching the node version to be `8.11.4` using nvm - `nvm use 8.11.4` solved my issue. (If there is no 8.11.4 version installed use `nvm install 8.11.4` instead)

```
$ expo start
Starting project at /Users/dugong/development/myApp
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
oteDev] Start server...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Busy] Launching SocketCluster
1555352786943 - Origin: Worker (PID 63541)
[Error] Error: Compilation of µWebSockets has failed and there is no pre-compiled binary available for your system. Please install a supported C++11 compiler and reinstall the module 'uws'.
at native (/Users/dugong/development/myApp/node_modules/socketcluster-server/node_modules/uws/uws.js:38:19)
```